# How can I create a UISplitViewController in my tab bar application (iPad)?

Tags: ios, ipad, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, ios5.1

I have seen several apps that make use of a `UISplitViewController` inside a tab. This is exactly what I need to do however I'm having several issues.

So far I have done the following:

In my app delegate class...

```
// Set up the cuts tab
UIViewController *splitViewController = [[SplitViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SplitViewController" bundle:nil];

// Set up the tab bar
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:splitViewController, nil];
```

Then in the `SplitViewController.h` is have...

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class LeftView;
@class RightView;

@interface SplitViewController : UIViewController
{
    UISplitViewController *splitView;
    LeftView *leftView;
    RightView *rightView;
}


@property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UISplitViewController *splitView;
@property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet LeftView *leftView;
@property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet RightView *rightView;


@end
```

Then in the corresponding .m file I have ...

```
#import "SplitViewController.h"

@implementation SplitViewController
@synthesize splitView, leftView, rightView;

#pragma mark - View Lifecycle

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) 
    {
        self.title = @"Tab A";
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"My_Icon"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view = splitView.view;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];

    self.splitView = nil;
    self.leftView = nil;
    self.rightView = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

The next thing I did was to create a `UITableViewController` class for `leftView` and a `UIViewController` class for `rightView`.

Finally I linked up the `IBOutlets` to the corresponding components and tried running it. However, when I run the app all is see is a black screen where I would expect to see the `UISplitViewController`.

I'm completely stumped at this point so any help would be really appreciated.

**FURTHER INFO:**

To be more specific I have been following this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1040/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uisplitview-tutorial) up to the section '**Making Our Model**', where I stopped because the `UISplitView` wasn't being displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [IntelligentSplitViewController](https://github.com/grgcombs/IntelligentSplitViewController).

Comment: This is a genuinely brilliant subclass - I cannot put into words how useful it truly is. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an answered post but I recently solved this in iOS6. I tried implementing the IntelligentSplitViewController but couldn't get it to work *all* the time - possibly because I was targeting iOS6. Basically my solution involved subclassing both UISplitViewController and UITabBarController and handling rotation events. I detail my solution in this [blog post](http://objectiveseesharp.wordpress.com/2013/01/20/uisplitviewcontroller-inside-uitabbarcontroller-in-ios6/). Hope this helps.